# How to push array of objects into state using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useState as `const [responses, setResponses] = useState([]);`

I get the response and log it as follows :

```
const tempResults = res.data.data;
console.log(tempResults.length);
console.log(tempResults);
```

The log shows as:

[image]

When I click to open the Array of 6 items, results are [image]. 
So it is an array of objects. 
I tried to set the initial value of the state as per the object

```
{
  "index": 0,
  "ds": "2020-03-06",
  "yhat_lower": -10712.5597359237,
  "yhat_upper": 25376.4649581317,
  "yhat": 6955.3671910982,
  "mape": 21.4472070205,
  "rmse": 667.0969808414,
  "mae": 475.3343871057,
  "smape": 5.143548286
}
```

But when I logged, the state only had the initial value and had not appended the response array.

I am setting state as :

```
setResponses(...responses, tempResults);
const x = typeof responses;
console.log("TypeOfResponse", x);
console.log("RESPONSES ", responses);
```

However, the state of the 'responses' object as per console is this:

[image]

So it is not able to save the Array object into `state`. What could be wrong? Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Try `setResponses([...responses, ...tempResults])`

Comment: Yes it worked out. I just have to figure out how to handle an array within an array, but that is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `res.data.data` is an array

then set to `setResponses` like this

```
setResponses(res.data.data)
```

or

```
setResponses([...responses, ...res.data.data])
```

Comment: Ok. Now i get the array of objects in the 'responses' state. However, when i access props.responses.map(item.mape), i get an array. So it seems to be a nested array.